# Close undecorated frames tkinter python

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a UI using tkinter in python. I want to make a full screen window for my UI, without any titles or border like an undecorated frame in Java. As described on http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm I used

```
root.overrideredirect(True)
```

It works fine and I have an full screen window, but I can't close this window using normal close operation like ALt+F4 unlike undecorated frames in Java. I need to add a functionality to close my overrideredirect window using keyboard Alt+F4 keys. How can I do that?

If not possible to add that functionality, can I use an another way to make a full screen window using any other command such that I have close with Alt+F4 keys functionality

Answer (score 0):

For me Alt+F4 works fine for an undecorated window, so i'm not sure what's going wrong for you.
That being said, you can of course make a button which destroys the window. This is probably best any way, since not everyone is familiar with (simple) keyboard shortcuts.

```
self.button_quit = Tk.Button(self.root, text='Quit', command=self.quit).pack

def quit(self):
    self.root.destroy()
```